# Circle action with a single fixed point

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Is there a closed manifold (smooth, compact with no boundary) that admits a smooth circle action with a single fixed point?

From what I understand such a manifold must have Euler characteristic one. An example of a closed manifold with Euler characteristic one should be the connected sum $\mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}^2\#T^4$ of the 2-complex projective space with the 4-torus, since
$$\chi (\mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}^2\#T^4)= \chi (\mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}^2)+ \chi (T^4) - \chi(S^4)=3+0-2=1. $$

Does this example already admit such a circle action?

Comment: I am curious to know why such a manifold must have Euler characteristic one?

Comment: There is another entry about this :)  Check out: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101815/euler-characteristic-expression-in-terms-the-number-of-fixed-points-of-an-math?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. In fact, every $\mathbb{R}P^{2n}$ admits a (smooth) circle action with exactly one fixed point. You can find a proof (as well as an extended discussion of related problems) in
*Circle Action with a Prescribed Number of Fixed Points* by Ping Li.

For completeness, here's an excerpt from Example $2.1$ in that paper:

> We view $\mathbb{R}P^{2n}$ as the unit ball in $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$ modulo the
> antipodal map on the boundary. It is easy to see the standard circle action
> on $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$ given by
> $(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n) \mapsto (z \cdot z_1, z \cdot z_2, \ldots, z \cdot z_n)$
> is compatible with the antipodal map on the boundary and thus can be factored to
> a circle action on $\mathbb{R}P^{2n}$. This circle action has precisely one
> fixed point, the origin.

Note the author uses superscripts to indicate the *real* dimension of a space, so $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$ is the complex space with $2n$ *real* dimensions that we would normally call $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Your particular example $\mathbb{C}P^2 \# T^4$ is orientable, which means it *cannot* admit an action with exactly $1$ fixed point. In *Circle Actions on Oriented Manifolds with Discrete Fixed Point Sets and Classification in Dimension $4$* by Donghoon Jang, we see (on page $2$):

> First, let us begin with small numbers of fixed points. If there is one fixed
> point, then the manifold must be a point.

I̶ ̶d̶o̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶o̶f̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶c̶l̶a̶i̶m̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶h̶a̶n̶d̶, but it means you'll need to consider nonorientable manifolds to get what you want.

**Edit:**
I found a proof in a different paper by Donghoon Jang, *Circle Actions on Oriented Manifolds with Few Fixed Points*. This is part of Lemma $2.1$, which crucially uses the Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Yes! Thats very helpful! Thanks a lot!